# Local Cache of CloudKit Records

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, swift4

There's a chapter called Maintaining Local Cache of CloudKit Records in CloudKit documentation on Apple's web site. However, everywhere online people say it's close to impossible to store offline data with CloudKit. I'm relatively new iOS developer. Did anybody tried implementing offline data storage (on device) as per Apple's docs?

Comment: What do you mean with store offline data? You mean store the data because device is offline and just send it to server when you get back online or?

Comment: By offline I mean storing data on the device. Let's say I have records with pictures and every time I access them it takes long time to load in a table view. So I need a mechanism to store offline and just update when necessary.

Comment: I usually have my own model object, and then when data changes I go and update the `CKRecord` (each model object has a unique ID that corresponds to `CKRecordID` of that object stored in CloudKit...

Comment: do you use core data?

Comment: I do not, but it will not make a difference if I used Core Data

Comment: so are you following directions from apple?: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW1

Comment: Yes, I have a custom private zone for example, but to be sure, before I update a `CKRecord` I first fetch the one that Apple has on server, than I compare if I have to change something (maybe changes on server are newer than what I have - in that case I store new data to my model), if local changes are newer I update the fetched `CKRecord` and save via `CKModifyRecordsOperation`

Comment: Did you come up with all the logic by yourself or followed any tutorials?

Comment: The login when to update is my own, but I learned CloudKit via tutorials and trial and error while developing apps for CloudKit

Answer (score 2):

If you want true, offline-first data for your app, then yes, you need to add a database of some kind.

Every time you update a record, save it to your database and push the updated record to CloudKit. You can also subscribe to CloudKit changes and update your local database as record changes come in.

Core Data and SQLite are common options. I happen to use the [Realm database](https://realm.io/products/realm-database), which I consider to be a bit simpler to use than Core Data or SQLite. I set it up so that my app's UI *only* interacts with the offline data in the database (so that it's always available). CloudKit and my Realm database work together to keep the data up-to-date, but my UI never tries to rely on the presence of transitory CloudKit records.

I hope that helps.